Confidance Interval to percentile from VGAM
How can I add a confidence interval to each quantile with a fill color similar to the line color using the VGAM or gamlss? Thankyou for your help.
I am using following code using package VGAM in R:
fit <- vgam(BMI ~ s(age, df = c(4,2)), lms.bcn(zero = 1), data = bmi.nz)
colors <- c("blue", "red", "green", "red","blue")

# Plot percentiles (fit) and confidence intervals (lower, upper)
qtplot( fit, perc=c(2.5,25,50,75,90), 
       lcol = colors, tcol ="blue", llwd = 2, pcol.arg="transparent",  llty.arg= c(3,2,1,2,3))



I am getting a graph like this:
enter image description here
